# read and combine series of html docs with php

Tags: php, html

I have a series of html docs that I want to combine using php. I need to load the contents of the html docs and display them all in one doc. How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: what exactly you want to combine ? What is there in your HTML files and what you want to display

Comment: What have you already done? Please, post your code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

$files = array('file1.html','file2.html','file3.html');
foreach($files as $file) require_once $file;
```

or use `require` if you want to include the same file multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Forget `require`, `require_once` and `include_once` and just use `include` which is the most performance function.

`include_once` and `require_once` are there to prevent circular dependencies, surely not for HTML; and `require` will throw a fatal error instead of an `E_WARNING` but will take more time.

You can aswell get the content in a buffer with:

```
$buffer = file_get_contents('index.html');
```

and decide when to echo it yourself.
Or you can finally use `ob_*` functions to get the buffer:

```
ob_start():
include('index.html');
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
```

Answer (score 0):

use include, include_once, require, require_once and add files to main doc

ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php